# How to override event when some value is inputted in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set complicated conditions.
My desired result is when I input some value and click the button, a confirmation `Have you input ?` will be alerted, and then `clicked with input` will be alerted, and if I don't input some value, `clicked without input` will be alerted.

But now, when I input some value, and click on the button, all three alerts appear together in this order-

`clicked without input` → `Have you input ?`→`clicked with input`.

How can I achieve the desired result when some value is inputted?

```js
const myFunc = () => {
  console.log("exec");
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',confirmation);
}

const confirmation = () => {
  const ret = confirm('Have you input ?');
  if(ret){
  alert("clicked with input")
  } else { 
  return false
  }
}

const clicked = () => {
  alert("clicked without input");
}
```

```html
<input oninput="myFunc()">
<button id="button" onclick="clicked()">open another window</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `value` of the input before triggering the `alert()`

```js
const clicked = () => {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (inputValue) {
      if (confirm('Have you input ?')){
        alert(`clicked with input: ${inputValue}`)
      }
  } else {
      alert("clicked without input");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<button id="button" onclick="clicked()">open another window</button>
```